# Query Function - Order By with Dates Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am using the query function to pull Google Form responses into a new sheet.  I want to order by the date but when I do so the query is blank. Funny enough, if I add "desc" to the query then it works fine but I want them in ascending order. Any ideas?

**Works**

```
=QUERY('Vacation Form Responses'!A1:F101, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F ORDER BY D desc")
```

**Does not work** - pulls in headers correctly but following rows are blank

```
=QUERY('Vacation Form Responses'!A1:F101, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F ORDER BY D")
```

---

```
=QUERY('Vacation Form Responses'!A1:F101, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F ORDER BY D asc")
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
=QUERY('Vacation Form Responses'!A1:F101, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F 
  where D is not null 
  order by D", 0)
```

btw your ascending formulas fork but results are at the bottom of the sheet eg if your sheet has 1000 rows you will see your query around row 1000